# How should I properly loop over a list on a gitconfig alias?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I created an alias on .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    test =  "!f() { \
        for l in "$@"; do \
          echo "$l"; \
        done; \
        }; f"
```

Considering the command :

```
git test "foo bar" last
```

I was expecting to get:

```
foo bar
last
```

However, I got:

```
foo
bar
last
```

It is a different behavior from a similar 'for' command on bash. Why did it happen? And how should I make this command to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Git strips double quotes from alias expansions.  Your alias definition, shrunken to a single line, is:

```
"!f() { for l in "$@"; do echo "$l"; done; }; f"
```

Git strips off all the unescaped double quotes (and of course the leading `!`), producing:

```
f() { for l in $@; do echo $l; done; }; f
```

You want the shell to see:

```
f() { for l in "$@"; do echo "$l"; done; }; f
```

which means you must give this to Git:

```
"!f() { for l in \"$@\"; do echo \"$l\"; done; }; f"
```

Now that each of the internal double quotes are escaped, Git will leave them there for the shell to see.

(If your script gets complex, I recommend *not* trying to write it as an alias.  If you have an executable script named `git-abc` anywhere on your `$PATH` and you run `git abc`, Git will run your `git-abc` script.  Note that when Git runs your script, Git has augmented its `$PATH` to include the `git-core` directory, so that you can use `. git-sh-setup` to obtain various useful subroutines.)

Answer (score 0):

Before post, I found out a way to achieve what I need. I rewrote the alias to:

```
[alias]
    test =  "!f() { IFS='\n'; \
        for l in "$@"; do \
          echo "$l"; \
        done; \
        }; f"
```

The IFS redefinition did the trick. I am just not sure if this is the best way to do it. I would appreciate different takes on the subject.